# Angular 2 - Unit test binding to nested custom form control

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular2-forms, angular2-testing, angular-forms

I've got a custom from control with selector `app-date-picker`. It implements `ControlValueAccessor`. I have a component called `MyPage` that contains this custom form control via:

```
<app-date-picker class="address__from-date" [(ngModel)]="fromDate"></app-date-picker>
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for `MyPage` that tests both directions of binding. I have done this for other form fields just fine, for example:

```
it('should bind zip code', fakeAsync(() => {
  const formControl = element.query(By.css('.address__zip-code input')).nativeElement;

  // model -> view
  component.zipCode = 76777;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  expect(formControl.value).toEqual('76777');

  // view -> model
  formControl.value = '89556';
  formControl.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

  expect(component.zipCode).toEqual(89556);
}));
```

My problem arises when I try to do this for my custom form control. So far, I can only test one direction of binding, and even so it is requiring the use of `ng-reflect-model`, which is just awful:

```
it('should bind from-date', fakeAsync(() => {
  const formControl = element.query(By.css('.address__from-date app-date-picker')).nativeElement;

  // model -> view
  component.fromDate = '01/2017';
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  expect(formControl.attributes['ng-reflect-model'].value).toEqual('01/2017');

  // view -> model
  // Not sure what to do here either
}));
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this? I'd like to:

1. Be able to test both directions of binding from the `MyPage` unit tests, so that I know I wired it up to the form controls correctly
2. Not have to use `ng-reflect-*`

**Other notes:**

The `MyPage` component is a standard component with a `fromDate` (and a `zipCode`) field.

The custom form field implements `ControlValueAccessor` correctly, has a `date` field, and uses an `<input>` internally, which itself is bound via `ngModel`:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="date" type="date">
```

*DatePickerComponent*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePickerComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class DatePickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  private propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

  private _date: string;
  get date(): string {
    return this._date;
  }

  @Input()
  set date(value: string) {
    this._date = value;
    this.propagateChange(value);
  }

  writeValue(newValue: any) {
    if (newValue !== undefined) {
      this.date = newValue;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    // Not used
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 8/10/2017**

So far, I have gotten close to what I want with `@ViewChild`:

```
@Component(...)
MyPageComponent {
 @ViewChild('fromDate') fromDatePicker: DatePickerComponent;
 ...
}
```

The `MyPage` template becomes (note the template reference variable `#fromDate`):

```
<app-date-picker #fromDate class="address__from-date" [(ngModel)]="fromDate">
</app-date-picker>
```

Then the test becomes:

```
it('should bind from-date', fakeAsync(() => {
  // model -> view
  component.info.fromDate = '01/2017';
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  expect(component.fromDatePicker.date).toEqual('01/2017');

  // view -> model
  component.fromDatePicker.date = '02/2017';

  expect(component.info.fromDate).toEqual('02/2017');
}));
```

Anyone know of a better way? This gets me by for now, though it's not optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, finally found an answer I'm happy with, as it avoids both `ng-reflect-*` and `@ViewChild`. Instead of calling `.nativeElement`, I can call `.componentInstance`. Then the test becomes simply:

```
it('should bind from-date', fakeAsync(() => {
  const formControl = element.query(By.css('.address__from-date app-date-picker')).componentInstance;

  // model -> view
  component.fromDate = '01/2017';
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  expect(formControl.date).toEqual('01/2017');

  // view -> model
  formControl.date = '02/2017';

  expect(component.fromDate).toEqual('02/2017');
}));
```

I'm still open if anyone has a better solution, but I'll mark this as the answer for now. Hope it helps anyone else running into this!